# Swift URLSession keep connect to server, not use dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I have a problem with session connecting, with current API I notice `streamTask` can create a TCP/IP connection task, all I found to use the code below:

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
session.streamTask(withHostName: iptxt.text!, port: Int(porttxt.text!)!).resume()
```

But `.resume()` didn't start the request I use the breakpoint to see, do I miss something?

**EDIT:** I want to develop an app like a commander in Windows(or terminal in Mac), so the connection must keep connecting until close the app or click the disconnect button. during the connection, I can send my own command and receive information from it.

I searched a lot of URLSession information from apple developer document, I think if the connection will connect only once by trigger something(button...) then disconnect, is that correct? 
If there's any suggestion or answer it will be appreciated.